# KnockoutJS - display raw object data in HTML

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

I want to display what's inside in my array variable.

In AngularJS I did only `{{ myArray }}`

but how can do it in KnockoutJS ?

Answer (score 2):

In knockout

```
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(myArray)" />
```